# is it possible to enable to serve mediawiki files with mediawiki content from any simple mediawiki server?

Tags: mediawiki

I understand that `mediawiki` server's its content from `mysql`.  I would like to serve my content from local files maybe `index.mediawiki` etc.  is that possible? any reference to such a solution? or any link which describes how to do it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Also, the database tables don't contain just article texts, they contain other info (e.g. about users) too. Can these be accessed from the database, or do they have to use files too?

Comment: @svick I'm using Google sites as a wiki. I exported it to disk for backup with Google sites liberation. The exported files are HTML. Then I used `pandoc` to convert to convert to `markdown` recursively and I wish go use it as backup wiki so I already have the `wiki` content as files. As for users I will try to have some mind of SSO to their Google account. I'm also. Considering pandocing to md files and using svn for authentication but I prefer media wiki.

Comment: Google sites are not MediaWiki wikis. Are you sure you are using MediaWiki? If so, are you just trying to make a static HTML version of the website to preserve it without a database etc.?